# ошибка в отправке fetch Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

я пытаюсь отправить fetch на сервер и получить ответ. но при отправке из firefox появляется ошибка "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.", а при отправке из хрома ошибки нет request отправляется но response не приходит

бекенд:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const jsonParser = express.json();

app.get("/testFetch", function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/static/index.html")
})

app.post("/api/test", jsonParser, function (request, response) {
    if (!request.body) return response.sendStatus(400);
    console.log("information was get");
    response.send("succes");
})

app.listen(port, ip);
```

html и js:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">
    </header>
    <body>
        <button oncklick="register()" id="testButton">click on me</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../authorization.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
document.getElementById("testButton").addEventListener("click", async function () {
    const password = PassWord.value;
    const username = UserName.value;
    const response = await fetch("/api/test", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "applications/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
    });
    if (response.ok === true) {
        const answer = await response.json();
        alert(answer);
    }
})
```

я пробовал копировать аналогичный код с learn.javascript и developer.mozzila, и он работал , пока я не вставлял его сюда.

Comment: возможно это cors, что в консоли пишет ?

Comment: в консоли пишет Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Answer (score 1):

С сервера посылаем строку

```
response.send("succes");
```

На клиенте ожидаем json

```
const answer = await response.json();
```

Причина вашей ошибки - попытка парсинга строки с использованием `JSON.parse`.

```js
JSON.parse("succes")
```

---

Вот как посылают с сервера json

```
response.json("succes");
```